# Stability / asymptotic stability of $x'=-t\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to determine the stability or asymptotic stability of $\bar x=0$ for

1. $x'=x\sin(t)$ and
2. $x'=-t\sin(x)$

$t\in \mathbb R$

For the first ODE we get the fundamental system $Y(t):=e^{-\cos t}$ and because $|Y(t)|\le e^1$, $\bar x=0$ is stable. And because $\lim_{t \to \infty}|Y(t)|\neq 0$, $\bar x=0$ is not asymptotically stable.

How can I do the same for the 2nd ode? It seems like the method of finding the fundamental system first would be too much work

Comment: Consider the Lyapunov function $V(x)=1-\cos x$

Comment: $t \in \mathbb R$, so I don't think $\frac{d}{dt}V(x(t))\le 0$ is fulfilled for negative $t$. For positive $t$ we get stability but how about asymptotic stability?

Comment: If some solution is defined on $[a,+\infty)$, then its stability does not depend on initial time $t_0\in [a,+\infty)$. Stability for $t_0>0$ implies stability for any $t_0$

Comment: The set $(-\pi,\pi)$ is an invariant set of the system. $\dot V$ is strictly negative on it except for $x=0$